# Aspose slides Python line chart label formatting

Tags: python, charts, pycharm, aspose

I'm trying to format my chart labels:

1. Set font bold;
2. Set visible label frame and bg/frame color.

I can't find any samples to do it.
My code:

```
  series = chart.chart_data.series.add(fact.get_cell(defaultWorksheetIndex, 0, 4, "asdf"), charts.ChartType.LINE)

  series.data_points.add_data_point_for_line_series(fact.get_cell(defaultWorksheetIndex, 1, 4, 80))
  series.data_points.add_data_point_for_line_series(fact.get_cell(defaultWorksheetIndex, 2, 4, 77))
  series.data_points.add_data_point_for_line_series(fact.get_cell(defaultWorksheetIndex, 3, 4, 83))
  series.data_points.add_data_point_for_line_series(fact.get_cell(defaultWorksheetIndex, 4, 4, 80))
  series.format.line.fill_format.fill_type = slides.FillType.SOLID
  series.format.line.fill_format.solid_fill_color.color = draw.Color.from_argb(79, 129, 189)
  series.plot_on_second_axis = True

  series.labels.default_data_label_format.show_value = True
  series.labels.default_data_label_format.is_number_format_linked_to_source = False
  series.labels.default_data_label_format.text_format.portion_format.font_height = 10
  series.labels.default_data_label_format.text_format.portion_format.font_bold.NullableBool = 1
  series.labels.default_data_label_format.text_format.portion_format.fill_format.fill_type = slides.FillType.SOLID
  series.labels.default_data_label_format.text_format.portion_format.fill_format.solid_fill_color.color = draw.Color.from_argb(31, 73, 125)
#  series.labels.default_data_label_format.line.fill_format.fill_type = slides.FillType.SOLID
#  series.labels.default_data_label_format.line.fill_format.solid_fill_color.color = draw.Color.from_argb(31, 73, 125)
```

[Like this excel sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VXNFU.jpg)
[Now I have this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ao1rS.jpg)

Comment: As requested in a response to [your similar question in Aspose' official forum](https://forum.aspose.com/t/formatting-line-chart-labels-using-aspose-slides-for-python/267200), we're waiting for a standalone runnable source code example along with the output PPTX file generated by using the latest version of 
Aspose.Slides for Python API on your system. We also need your expected PPTX file showing the desired Chart. You can use Microsoft PowerPoint to create the expected PPTX file. Please compress these resources into ZIP format and attach .zip file in Aspose' forum for further investigation.